# Sublime Text 2 Not Showing In Right Click >> Open With >> Other Application

Tags: sublimetext2, default, ubuntu-14.04, right-click, open-with

I am running on Ubuntu 14.04 and when I right click on a file and do `Open With >> Other Application` and click on `Show All Applications`, Sublime Text 2 does not appear. When I installed it originally I ran this command:

```
sudo sublime /usr/share/applications/defaults.list
```

and I changed all occurrences of `gedit.desktop` to `sublime.desktop`. However, it still opens everything with gedit by default. How can I get Sublime Text 2 to show up when right clicking and choosing Open With? And why is gedit still default? Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

Here what you can achieve:

[image]

**NOTE:** This is for Windows users, not sure if it will work on other operating systems.

Open `regedit.exe`

### FOR FOLDERS

Navigate to this key using the tree on the right: `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\`

Create a new key in the **shell key** with any name like: `Sublime` or `Open with Sublime Text` or `Sublime Text`

There will be a key with a **Name:** `(Default)` and enter the **Data:** `Open as Sublime Project`

Create a new **Binary Value** with Name: `Icon` and enter the **Data:** `C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe` *(Make sure you change the version of the Sublime Text you are using)*

Create a new key in the key name *(`Sublime` or `Open with Sublime Text` or `Sublime Text`)* with **Name:** `command`

There will be a key *(in that command key)* with a **Name:** `(Default)` and enter the *(Choose any one of the option below)*

1. **Data:** `C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe -n "%1"` *(If you want to open the project in new sublime window)*
2. **Data:** `C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe "%1"` *(If you want to open the project in sublime window, which is already running or you are currently using)*

### FOR FILES

Navigate to this key using the tree on the right: `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\`

Create a new key in the **shell key** with any name like: `Sublime` or `Open with Sublime Text` or `Sublime Text`

There will be a key with a **Name:** `(Default)` and enter the **Data:** `Open with Sublime`

Create a new **Binary Value** with Name: `Icon` and enter the **Data:** `C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe` *(Make sure you change the version of the Sublime Text you are using)*

Create a new key in the key name *(`Sublime` or `Open with Sublime Text` or `Sublime Text`)* with **Name:** `command`

There will be a key *(in that command key)* with a **Name:** `(Default)` and enter the *(Choose any one of the option below)*

1. **Data:** `C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe -n "%1"` *(If you want to open the file in new sublime window)*
2. **Data:** `C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe "%1"` *(If you want to open the file in sublime window, which is already running or you are currently using)*